# How to save pdf in Cordova Android from dataURL

Tags: cordova, pdf, ngcordova

I need to save dataURL pdf file in phone's directory in Android using Cordova with ngCordova.My code is Given below:-

```
var dataURL="data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjMKJf////8KNiAwIG9iago8PAovVHlwZSAvRX...";
$cordovaFile.createFile(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory,dataURL, true)
          .then(function (success) {
             alert('success');
          }, function (error) {
            alert('Fails');
          });
```

It not working.I need to save PDF in dataURL format using Cordova Android.How to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this code

```
  var dataURL="data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjMKJf////8KNiAwIG9iago8PAovVHlwZSAvRX...";
  $cordovaFile.writeFile(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory,'filename',dataURL, true)
                      .then(function (success) {
                         alert('Download Completed. Check your Internal/External Storage..');
                      }, function (error) {
                        alert('Fails');
                      });
```

Comment: This method did not work for me. The file was not encoded correctly and had to use the [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998908/convert-data-uri-to-file-then-append-to-formdata)

Answer (score 1):

Please read [documentation](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/)

`createFile(path, file, replace)` function only creates new file without writing it.

You need to use `writeFile(path, file, data, replace)`

Comment: What result do you get? Do you need just to store dataURL contents or save it as .pdf file?